# RLC-circuit, laplace transformation

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

[image]

So i have a circuit where R1 = 5 Ω, R2 = 2 Ω, L = 1 H, C = 1/6 F ja E = 2 V.          And i need to figure out what is i<sub>L</sub> when t=0.5s with  laplace transform.
Switch opens when t=0
When t<0 i got i<sub>L</sub>(0)=1A and U<sub>c</sub>(0)=2V for initial values.
When t>0 circuit will look like
[image]

And now i got for KVL i got

$$  E=U_L+U_R+U_C+U_C(0)$$ 
$$  E=Li_L'+i_LR_1+\int\frac{i_L}{C}+U_C(0)=0 $$ 
And now in need to do laplace transform.
$$  E/s=L(sI(s)-i_L(0)) + I(s)R_1 + \frac{1}{Cs}I(s) + \frac{U_C(0)}{C}$$
After adding known values
 $$  -I(s)s-\frac{6I(s)}{s}-5I(s)+1=0$$
And know for I(s)
$$  I(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+5s+6}$$
For partial fractions i got
$$  I(s)=\frac{3}{s+3}-\frac{2}{s+2}$$
And then for inverse transformation 
$$  I(t)=3e^{-3t}-2e^{-2t}$$
But now i got that I(0.5)=-0.066 which is wrong.

Comment: Your final equation gives \$I(0.5)=-0.066\$

Answer (score 0):

I've already replied to this question yesterday and also replied to your comment on where you committed a mistake. So, please take a look at that.

Also, here you've written the equation wrongly after taking the Laplace transform. The last term would be V<sub>c</sub>(0)/s and not V<sub>c</sub>/C.

[Check the method here which I replied to yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338322/circuit-analysis-laplace-transform/338334#338334)